# Problem aligning button to the end of the navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried to align a button inside the navbar to the right end.

The black button always stays next to the other elements.

I´ve been using bootstrap as a CSS Library for this school project.

Image of the navbar:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiI32.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #d0f0c0;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Quarere</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pesquisa Avançada</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Casas</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Use "me-auto" in your "navbar-nav" <ul> container

See the codepen of the updated code: 
https://codepen.io/mudasirh/pen/OJwxYLR

Comment: The code working fine for bootstrap-4